# Loading data dvds

Tags: filemanager

I switched to Ubuntu and would like to load my music collection onto my drive. I have about 20 gigs on dvds, audio cds I can load, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how the music is stored on the cd/dvd.

- If they are audio cd's you can convert them from WAV to OGG or MP3 with [soundconverter](http://packages.ubuntu.com/soundconverter) [image: Install soundconverter].
- CD/DVD with OGG or MP3 files on them:

Insert the CD/DVD.
Nautilus will show a popup with the contents of the cd/dvd and you can copy/paste them to a harddisk.